# Can HTTP PUT request have application/x-www-form-urlencoded as the Content-Type?

Tags: rest, http, content-type, put, specifications

Is it valid to send form data in an HTTP PUT request? If you could point me to a spec then that would be great.

I have gone through the HTTP 1.1 spec. But I did not find whether PUT requests can have form data or not.

I am using Java for creating and accessing RESTful webservices. POST supports `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the Content-Type.

From the specification, I understand that POST is for creating a new resource (a subresource to the resource identified by the request URI) and PUT is for create or update a resource.

But my doubt is whether PUT method also can have form data in it?  I trying to find out whether it is fine according to the spec. And I can't find anything about this in the HTTP 1.1 spec.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can use application/x-www-form-urlencoded with PUT.  The HTTP spec does not limit what methods can be used with what media types.

The currently in-progress Httpbis spec has a significantly expanded discussion of PUT https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-14#page-18

Answer (score 4):

Since the [PUT method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.6) is used to store the enclosed [entity](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-7) under the supplied URI and the [*Content-Type* header field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.17) is an [entity header field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-7.1), it is legitimate to use a *Content-Type* header field in a PUT request.

Now the remaining question is whether the receiving server can handle such request and *Content-Type* information appropriately. In worst case it can’t handle the *Content-Type* header field and returns a 501 response:

> The recipient of the entity MUST NOT ignore any *Content-**
> (e.g. *Content-Range*) headers that it does not understand or implement
> and MUST return a 501 (Not Implemented) response in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the HTTP spec from the wc3

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

Additionally, here are the pages for Content-Type

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17

and PUT

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6

If there is a specific language you want help with in regard to your HTTP PUT, please update your question with the specifics